# Microsoft access 2007 filter

Tags: microsoft-access-2007

Is there a setting in Microsoft Access 2007 to disable toggle filter button permanently? Everytime I load a form the filter button is toggled automatically..

Answer (score 1):

Deactivate AutoFilter. If you want to disable the filters completely, simply deselect the AutoFilter option while the table is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If you open your form in design mode and open up the properties for the form, on the 'data' tab, you will see an option called 'Allow filters'. If you select 'NO' then this toggle filter button will be disabled when you load the form.